# Create a token pattern based on the concatenation of some given words

Tags: python, regex, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I have a list of keywords, for example:

`keywords = ['airbnb.com', 'booking', 'deliveroo.uk - UK', ...]`

My goal is to define the parameter `token_pattern` of `CountVectorizer` by concatenating all keywords.

The idea is this:

`token_pattern = '|'.join([pattern_keyword_1, pattern_keyword_2, ...])`

What interests me is that it matches the exact occurrences in the text and not the substrings.

For example, if I have `'def.com'` in the keywords I DON'T want it to match `'abcdef.com'`.

Is it possible to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `rf'\b(?:{"|".join(map(re.escape, words))})\b'`